# writing escaped or unescaped HTML into sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, insert, escaping

i scrape HTML pages and write certain values into an sqlite database.

my question is: should the values, which i insert into the database, be html escaped or unescaped? what is best practice?

right now, e.g., one value looks like this in my db (note the escaped ampersand):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database itself does not care.

It is your choice whether you escape the values before writing them to the DB, or after reading them from the DB.
However, you might need to apply different escaping algorithms in different contexts (URL, HTML, XML, JSON, CSV, etc.), and if you write HTML code to an .html file, you need no escaping at all.
So it would be a bad idea to force the values in the DB to have one specific one.